# I have a query which does not return result with the desired alias names of columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, alias

The following is my query which does not return result with the desired alias column names:

```
with d as (select distinct emp.ahrims_id, rank.name as rank 
from hr_employee as emp, ana_rank as rank, 
unit_identification_code as uic, record_record as rec
where emp.unit_identificatin_code_id = uic.id and
rec.hr_employee_id = emp.id and
rank.id = emp.rank_id
and uic.code in ('Z00100','Z00200','Z00300','Z00400','Z00450','Z00500','Z00698','Z00600',
'Z00699','Z00680','Z00700','Z00697','Z00800','Z00900','Z01000','Z01100',
'Z01200','Z01300','Z39000','Z39012','Z10000','Z10005','Z10007','Z10009',
'Z10100','Z10101','Z10200','Z10300','Z10301','ZACA97','ZOCG01','ZACA99',
'ZACA98','ZOCG02','Z10400','Z10500','Z10600','Z10700','Z10800','Z11000',
'Z36000','Z37000','Z20000'))
select(select count(*) as "GSG1 Military NCO" from d where rank in 
('MSG','SFC','SGM','SGT','SSG','G1','G2','G3','G4','G5')),
(select count(*) as "GSG1 Military SDR" from d where rank in ('SDR','G6')),
(select count(*) as "GSG1 Civilian NCO" from d where rank in ('Civ11','Civ12','Civ13','Civ14','Civ15')),
(select count(*) as "GSG1 Civilian SDR" from d where rank in ('Civ16'))
```

It returns:

```
  ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column?
----------+----------+----------+----------
     1615 |      695 |        0 |        1
```

My desired result:

```
   GSG1 Military NCO | GSG1 Military SDR | GSG1 Civilian NCO | GSG1 Civilian SDR
---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------
     1615            |      695          |        0          |        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the aliases for the columns outside the subqueries:

```
with d as (
  select distinct emp.ahrims_id, rank.name as rank 
  from hr_employee as emp, ana_rank as rank, 
       unit_identification_code as uic, record_record as rec
  where emp.unit_identificatin_code_id = uic.id and
        rec.hr_employee_id = emp.id and
        rank.id = emp.rank_id and
        uic.code in (
          'Z00100','Z00200','Z00300','Z00400','Z00450','Z00500','Z00698','Z00600',
          'Z00699','Z00680','Z00700','Z00697','Z00800','Z00900','Z01000','Z01100',
          'Z01200','Z01300','Z39000','Z39012','Z10000','Z10005','Z10007','Z10009',
          'Z10100','Z10101','Z10200','Z10300','Z10301','ZACA97','ZOCG01','ZACA99',
          'ZACA98','ZOCG02','Z10400','Z10500','Z10600','Z10700','Z10800','Z11000',
          'Z36000','Z37000','Z20000')
  )
select (select count(*) from d where rank in ('MSG','SFC','SGM','SGT','SSG','G1','G2','G3','G4','G5')) as "GSG1 Military NCO",
       (select count(*) from d where rank in ('SDR','G6')) as "GSG1 Military SDR",
       (select count(*) from d where rank in ('Civ11','Civ12','Civ13','Civ14','Civ15')) as "GSG1 Civilian NCO",
       (select count(*) from d where rank in ('Civ16')) as "GSG1 Civilian SDR"
```